# Running adb from PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, centos6, android

I moved from Ubuntu to CentOS and I now have a problem running `adb` from PHP.

I am trying to execute `shell_exec("/path/to/adb devices");`

and I get:

```
ADB server didn't ACK
failed to start daemon
error cannot connect to daemon
daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037
```

Of course `adb` is not able to start because it is already running and listening on port 5037 and If I try to run `adb devices` as root or as a regular user from the command line it returns all connected devices.

This configuration was previously working with Ubuntu.

What is the difference? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to say it's a 90% chance it's SELinux related. You can confirm it by looking for entries in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

CentOS has SELinux enabled by default.

When you run `adb` from your PHP script, it is most likely running under `httpd`'s security context, which doesn't permit outgoing network connections.

The *quick* fix is to allow `httpd` to make outgoing network connections:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Keep in mind that this will allow outgoing connections to anywhere.

The *secure* fix is to write a local policy confining `adb` and allowing it to connect to port 5037, access USB devices, etc., but this is a *lot* of work...